# Найти элемент в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

Вот пример массива. Он может быть большим.

```
Arr = [{'id':12, 'users':[1, 2, 3, 4]}, {'id':13, 'users':[6, 7, 8, 9]}]
```

Какой самый оптимальный вариант узнать id, зная, например users = 8 (должен вернуть 13)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам придётся пройтиcь по всем `id` вручную и для каждого проверить наличие нужного `users`. Как-то так:

```
user = 8
Arr.find((x) => x.users.includes(user)).id
```

---

Но на самом деле, это будет работать достаточно долго на больших объёмах данных из-за сложности `O(N)`.

Простейшей быстрой альтернативой будет использование `Map`. Вы можете для каждого `user` хранить свой `id` и находить его приблизительно за `O(1)`, потому что Map - хеш-таблица.

Впрочем, при конкретно таком решении вам будет уже намного сложнее изменить `id` сразу для всех пользователей. Если вам это надо. Если надо, я могу дополнить ответ.

```
idByUser = new Map()

idByUser.set(1, 12);
idByUser.set(2, 12);
idByUser.set(8, 13);
...

user = 8
console.log(idByUser.get(user));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107804/discussion-on-answer-by-witaway-----).

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [{'id':12, 'users':[1, 2, 3, 4]}, {'id':13, 'users':[6, 7, 8, 9]}];
arr.filter((item)=>{
   return item.users.includes(8)
})
```

Наверное так

Comment: разве для большого массива создать еще массив это не тяжело будет?

Comment: Хм, да, filter долго работает